# tabItem doenst display R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have multiple tabItem in an r shiny app.When I comment out the second tabItem the content in the first tabItem is displayed correctly but when I have both the tabItem I can see the content for the second tab only.

Below is the code for the UI.r

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(plotly)


dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Loyalty Monthly Scorecard", titleWidth = 300),
  ## Sidebar content
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("ATC Topline",tabName = "atc_topline"),
    menuItem("Guidelines & KPI", tabName = "guidelines")
  )),
  ## Body content
  dashboardBody(tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "atc_topline",
            fluidRow(
              box(
                title = "ATC Topline Plot",
                width = 12,
                solidHeader = TRUE,
                status = "primary",
                plotlyOutput("plot"),
                collapsible = T
              )
            )),
    # # Second tab content
    tabItem(tabName = "guidelines",
            fluidRow(
              includeHTML("include.html")
            ))
  ))
)
```

Comment: `include.html` is not available.

Comment: I have it inside the file structure and it shows up correctly. The plot doesnt show when I have the  tabName="guidelines"

Answer (score 0):

Though enough problem statement is not given but tried to replicate the same and found no problem.

here is my code:

```
ui.R

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(plotly)


dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Loyalty Monthly Scorecard", titleWidth = 300),
  ## Sidebar content
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("ATC Topline",tabName = "atc_topline"),
    menuItem("Guidelines & KPI", tabName = "guidelines")
  )),
  ## Body content
  dashboardBody(tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "atc_topline",
            fluidRow(
              box(
                title = "ATC Topline Plot",
                width = 12,
                solidHeader = TRUE,
                status = "primary",
                plotlyOutput("plot"),
                collapsible = T
              )
            )),
    # # Second tab content
    tabItem(tabName = "guidelines",
            fluidRow(
              includeHTML("test.html")
            ))
  ))
)


Server.R

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

output$plot<-renderPlotly({
  ggplotly(
    ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = cyl)) + 
      geom_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ x) + 
      geom_point()) 
})


})
```

The html file is a basic html file:

```
<html>
<head>
header
</head>
<body>
Body
</body>

</html>
```

Please try it.Also clear your problem statement.